# c# httpwebrequest follow redirect

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

Httpwebrequest doesn't seem to be following the auto redirect from request

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Https://www.example.com);
request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
```

which redirects to

```
https://www.example.com/pageunknown
```

however

```
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse()
```

is reading the contents from

```
Https://www.example.com
```

and not the redirects content

```
https://www.example.com/pageunknown
```

how can I get it so that the redirection is followed and httpwebresponse reads from the redirection page and not the original url/request?

Comment: What exactly is the response from the first request? (i.e. how is the redirect being delivered?)

Comment: How does the page do the redirect? `AllowAutoRedirect` only redirects if the redirection is done via HTTP headers, not if done by Javascript..

Comment: It would be much easier to answer if you provide real url on which this behavior can be reproduced.

Comment: @stuartd redirect is done via http headers I believe as the location of the redirect is in response headers

Comment: Id suggest @CsharpLearning that rather than believe you would do better to put a web capture up and see what it does rather than assume.